# Xamarin forms ListView Search

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

I can't seem to get it to update correctly it just displays the first 2 items of the list.

I'm receiving json Data from a web API And I just want to be able to search threw the listview for a name and either display it, I've tried quite a few Example's of this But can't seem to get it to actually work, Do I need to have the list be Encapsulated & Subscribed to the INotify?

```xml
  <StackLayout>

      <SearchBar TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged"></SearchBar>   
        <FlexLayout  Wrap="Wrap" Direction="Row" JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly" >
            <flv:FlowListView x:Name="productsListView"

                     FlowColumnCount="2" HasUnevenRows="false" RowHeight="320"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      SeparatorVisibility="None"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Name}"
                      >

                <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="5">
                            <Frame BorderColor="#f39000" HeightRequest="310" >
                                <StackLayout   Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="5">

                                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" x:Name="idlabel" Text="{Binding name}">

                                    </Label>
                                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150"
                                            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                                            Source = "{Binding description}">
                                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>



                                    <Button Text="See Products" 
                                            Padding="5"
                                            FontSize="Small"
                                            BorderColor="#f39000"
                                            BackgroundColor="#f39000"
                                            CornerRadius="10"
                                            TextColor="White"
                                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            Clicked="SupplierClicked" 
                                            BindingContext="{Binding id}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView>
        </FlexLayout>
      </StackLayout>
```

```cs
public List<ProductTag> x;
public async Task InitAsync()
{

    var p = await wc.Tag.GetAll(new Dictionary<string, string>() {

                   { "per_page", "100" } });

                x = p;
                productsListView.FlowItemsSource = p;
}

 private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //thats all you need to make a search

            productsListView.BeginRefresh();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue))
                productsListView.ItemsSource = x;
            else
                productsListView.ItemsSource = x.Where(i => i.name.Contains(e.NewTextValue));

            productsListView.EndRefresh();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SearchBar_TextChanged, I think you are not feeding the source of the FlowListView in the right way. Instead of productsListView.ItemsSource, it should be:

```
productsListView.FlowItemsSource = x.Where(i => i.name.Contains(e.NewTextValue));
```

Comment: uhhg, I do this far to often.  And yes that is correct That and I'd need to Cast to a list in my case so ```productsListView.FlowItemsSource = x.Where(i => i.name.Contains(e.NewTextValue)).toList();```